# Cakephp 3 - Subtracting a value from the database

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-3.0

Hi i'm new to cakephp and trying to figure out how things work.

So i have two tables, One is Customer **Payments** & the other is Customer **Charges**. How do i subtract a value from **Charges** when i add a value to **Payments** table?

E.g - Customer X has a charge of 100. When i select customer X from payments and select the payment for 20. The answer should be 80 in the **Charges** table. And it should get recorded on the **Payments** table that the Customer X has made his payment as well.

I'm submitting the value from a form. And sending it to the Payments Controller.

```
 public function addPaymentsCustomer()
 {
     $this->viewBuilder()->layout(false);
     $payment = $this->Payments->newEntity();
         if ($this->request->is('post')) {
             $payment = $this->Payments->patchEntity($payment, $this->request->data);

             if ($this->Payments->save($payment)) {
                 $this->Flash->success(__('The payment has been saved.'));
                return $this->redirect( '/payments' );
             } else {
                $this->Flash->error(__('The payment could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
                return $this->redirect( '/payments' );
             }
             $this->Flash->error(__('Error.. Please, try again.'));
            return $this->redirect( '/payments' );
         }
 }
```

How can i do the same and subtract the value from the **Charges** table?

Where can i do the calculation and how to do it?

This is my form where i send values to the controller.

```
<form role="form" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8" action="/add-payments-customer">
      <div style="display:none;"><input type="hidden" name="_method" value="POST"/></div>
      <br style="clear:both">
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="input-group col-md-5 col-lg-5 col-sm-5 col-xs-12">
          <select class="form-control" style="background-color: #F9F9F9;" name="customer_id" id="customer_id" onchange="this.form.submit()">
            <option style="padding-top: 20px;">Select a Customer</option>
            <?php
            if (!empty($CustomerInfo)) { 
              foreach ($CustomerInfo as $Customers):        
                ?> 
              <option value="<?= h($Customers->id)?>"><?= h($Customers->name)?></option>
            <?php endforeach;  } ?> 
          </select>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control secondlead" id="description" name="description" placeholder="Description" required>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="number" id="amount" name="amount" class="form-control secondlead" placeholder="Amount">
      </div>
      <div class="pull-left">
        <button type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary greenbtn">Send</button>
      </div>
      <div style="margin-top: 10px" class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
        <p class="text-center"><?= $this->Flash->render() ?></p>
      </div>
    </form>
```

Tables 
 Payments & Charges both have a FK of Customer_id.

Comment: Do you mean customer has charges amount already stored in table and you need to reduced that charges amount when the payment completed ?

Comment: Yes exactly, And also when the submission is done Payments record gets added with the customer ID and at the same time charges of that specific customer gets subtracted.

Comment: all right, if you add your form it will be more clear! also mention if two tables are in relations!

Comment: You can do it by creating triggers in mysql OR you can execute another query to update amount of the Charges table after success. Check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21848149/cakephp-save-update-data-from-old-data-value-new-value

Comment: @ManoharKhadka hi i added the form that i use to send data to the PaymentsController.

Comment: @AmanRawat I tried that method but it doesn't quite work.

Comment: Is Payments are saving successfully?

Comment: @AmanRawat Yes when i submit the form it gets saved. The place i am stuck is subtracting the payment value from **Charges**.

Comment: What if i **$this->loadModel('Charges');** inside the **Payments** Controller and subtract and save the value, so both fields get updated at the same time? How can i do that ? :S

Comment: No offense, but I hope that you're not dealing with real money?

Comment: @ndm Hi, Not entirely. Why did you ask like that? lol

Comment: Because you shouldn't ask such questions when you deal with actual money, you should know how stuff like that works, otherwise you'd be the wrong person for the job. No offense, I don't want to step on anyones toes, it's just that dealing with money a very sensitive subject, and requires very profound programming knowledge, especially of all the things that can go wrong.

Comment: @ndm Dude no no i understand, I'm just doing this to learn cakephp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply add little logic:

**At Payments controller:**

```
public function addPaymentsCustomer()
{
    $this->viewBuilder()->layout(false);
    $payment = $this->Payments->newEntity();
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
     $payment = $this->Payments->patchEntity($payment, $this->request->data);
     $this->loadModel('Charges');
     $data['amount'] = $this->request->data['amount'];
     $data['customer_id'] = $this->request->data['customer_id'];
     if ($this->Payments->save($payment)) {
         $this->Flash->success(__('The payment has been saved.'));
         $this->Charges->updateCharge($data); // update charges
        return $this->redirect( '/payments' );
     } else {
        $this->Flash->error(__('The payment could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
        return $this->redirect( '/payments' );
     }
     $this->Flash->error(__('Error.. Please, try again.'));
    return $this->redirect( '/payments' );
    }
}
```

**At charges table:**

```
public function updateCharge($data = []) {
    $customer_id = $data['customer_id'];
    $charge = $this->find()
                    ->where(['Charges.customer_id' => $customer_id])
                    ->first();

    $previousAmount = $charge->amount;
    $newAmount = $previousAmount - $data['amount'];

    $charge->customer_id = $customer_id;
    $charge->amount = $newAmount;
    if($this->save($charge)) {
        // updated
    }
}
```

And I just suppose you have 'amount' field in charges table as well!

Comment: Welcome mate..!

Comment: @ManoharKhadka Put this in  transaction as one fails the whole process can be roll backed

Comment: Not only that things will break when the second save fails, as mentioned by @AmanRawat, this is also generally prone to race conditions. I don't want to sound mean, but if I would have hired someone to build a system that deals with money, I'd immediately fire you when you came up with something like this.

Comment: @KasunWijesekara I'm referring to the code in this answer, Aman Rawats code is possibly "more safe" (there might be something wrong with it too though), but just wrapping things in a transaction isn't neccesarily "safe enough". Do you for example know what transaction isolation level you're operating with? If you can't answer that question, or don't even know what an isolation level is, then you'd be in trouble if you'd deal with real money. I may sound a little hysterical, but it's a sensitive topic, and it's dangerous when code like this spreads.

Comment: @ndm No i dont know that. I'm trying out some examples so  i can get familiar with everything. And no this is not a real world example. If you could provide me with some sources i'm more than grateful to learn about the topic!

Comment: @KasunWijesekara Take a scenario, suppose Payments data is saved successfully in database but `updateCharge` encountered with an error so it will not update the amount in charges table. This will be not good but if you use transaction and whenever the error occurred you can rollback the transaction. Check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18496465/when-should-i-use-mysql-transactions#answer-18496876

Comment: @AmanRawat and ndm I highly appreciate for the suggestions you have provided and yes this is simply a logic and we need to work with transaction management to make it complete, and link provided above for transaction is very helpful for this all.

Answer (score 0):

Do like this

```
use Cake\Datasource\ConnectionManager;// At the top of file



$conn = ConnectionManager::get('default');
$conn->begin(); // Start transaction

if ($this->Payments->save($payment)) {
    $this->loadModel('Customers');
    $customer = $this->Customers->get($payment->customer_id);
    $customer->amount = $customer->amount + $payment->amount;
    if($this->Customers->save($customer)){
        $conn->commit(); // Commit transaction
        $this->Flash->success(__('The payment has been saved.'));
    } else {
        $conn->rollback();// Rollback transaction
        $this->Flash->error(__(json_encode($customer->errors()))); // Shows what get wrong
    }
    return $this->redirect('/payments');
} else {
    $conn->rollback();// Rollback transaction
    $this->Flash->error(__(json_encode($payment->errors()))); // Shows what get wrong
    return $this->redirect('/payments');
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work, gives the "Something went wrong! Please try again" error and the charges won't get subtracted.

Comment: Is amount is the field name or something else? IF you can provide the table structure as well, will be more helpfull

Comment: I tried this option but the Payments doesn't get saved. And the value doesn't get deducted as well.

Comment: Yes it's the same. And i also added $this->loadModel('Charges');
    if($this->Charges->updateAll(['amount'=>'amount + '.$payment->amount],['id'=>$payment->customer_id])){ 

because the model should be charges, but the issue still continued.

Comment: Thank you for the help bro. Manohar's answer works for me. I'm really new to this subject and i appreciate all the help i get. Thanks!